# How to access version 4.0 component from version 1.1

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, .net-remoting

We have an ASP.NET application which has been built up on version 1.1 Now we need to incorporate a new functionality in Version 4.0 and this includes a user control having a grid and a number of other controls. We need to display this user control inside a page (in a frame) in .Net version 1.1, Both these applications are in different servers too. Is it possible to add the new feature, which is created on Version 4.0, into Version 1.1 . If so which is the simple and the best way?

Comment: Can you elaborate why the question is targeted with WCF, web-services, and remoting? Apart from that your question feels like it's lacking details, is very broad, or both.